# Fatal error: Class 'App\User' not found in public_html/laravel/app/CreateUser.php

Tags: php, class, laravel

I did a very simple CreateUser.php under app folder as follows.

```
$user = new App\User;
$user->name='John Doe';
$user->email='john@example.com';
$user->password=bcrypt('password');
```

But I got error message Fatal error: Class 'App\User' not found in public_html/laravel/app/CreateUser.php. Any ideas? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your routes

```
Route::get('/createuser', function () {
    'as' => 'createuser',
    'uses' => 'UserController@creteUser'
});
```

In your controller create UserController.php

```
use App\User;

public function creteUser(User $user)
    {

        $user->name='John Doe';
        $user->email='john@example.com';
        $user->password=bcrypt('password');
        $result = $user->save();

        if($result){
            return redirect ('createuser')->with('success', 'User Created Successfully'); 
        }

        return redirect ('createuser')->with('error', 'Failed to create User');


    }
```

Comment: even I put namespace App;use App\User; it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include User model first to work your query. See the link below, you will get good idea how to use it.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers

Comment: Seems there are no easy ways to do that. I need to take time to figure it out. Many Thanks.

Comment: If you have experience in php and mysql then Laravel is very easy to learn.Just go through the Laravel webste or search Laravel tutorial from google.
Here are the links:
1.) https://laravel.com
2.) https://laracasts.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried

```
$user = new User;
```

instead of

```
$user = new App\User;
```

and, Make sure you are created model (User)and also specify namespace (use App\User) at the top of your controller.